# Unpacking single file from jar gives java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar

I have a built jar file and want to extract a single file out of it.

However when I run the following command to extract a single file from the jar:

```
jar -xf test.jar example.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:88)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:875)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:236)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1149)
```

Other pages on StackOverflow with this error mention the jar could be corrupted, but if I try to extract *every* file:

```
jar -xf test.jar
```

That command runs successfully with no errors and extracts every file, so I'm not sure if the jar is actually corrupted.

UPDATE - as a workaround I can extract the file successfully with:

```
unzip test.jar example.txt
```

However if I try editting the txt file and re-adding it to the jar with:

```
zip test.jar example.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
zip warning: expected 43976 entries but found 109512

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (test.jar)
```

Even weirder is I can successfully add the editted txt file to the jar with:

```
jar -uf test.jar example.txt
```

Comment: How did you build the jar file? Can you describe how others can replicate your work so far?

Comment: Created Jenkins Maven job to build a pom.xml using Java 1.8_92 JDK. Build was successful and created the jar. SSH'd onto Jenkins server, cd'd to job workspace and tried running command on the jar. JDK of server matches the JDK of the Jenkins job.

Also deployment of the jar and starting it via Tomcat is successful and the application runs properly.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example (including the Pom) and upload?

Comment: (After edit) The jar file is broken. Your post does not include enough information to determine how it happened.